# TextBox.SelectAll() does not work with TAB

Tags: c#, winforms, highlight, maskedtextbox

I am using `maskedTextBox.SelectAll()` to highlight the text in the MaskedTextBox in the `Enter` and `MouseDown` events.

It works when I use the mouse, but I go to that textbox by pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, it does not work.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [`GotFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus(v=VS.71).aspx) event?

> When you change the focus by using the keyboard (TAB, SHIFT+TAB, and so on), by calling the Select or SelectNextControl methods, or by setting the ContainerControl.ActiveControl property to the current form, focus events occur in the following order:

It then goes on to list the events that are fired. It looks like this fires when the mouse is used so you might only need this handler.

Comment: Chris! I wanted to use GotFocus but could not Find it in the list of the events in the properties window... where is it?

Comment: @BDotA - I found it via the MSDN - it's an event on `Control` so it might not appear. Try adding it manually.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that explains why it is not listed in the properties window.. i will try it.