# MaskedTextBox.SelectAll on GotFocus doesn't work with mouse

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, maskedtextbox

I want to select all the contents of a `MaskedTextBox` when the clicks (or tabs onto) the control, so they can easily replace the old content. I tried calling `SelectAll()` in the `Enter` event, but that didn't work at all.

I switched to using the `GotFocus` event, which works great when tabbing through controls, but doesn't work when I click on it with the mouse. I would only want to select all the contents when first entering/focusing on the control (subsequent clicks might be used to position the cursor to edit the existing text).

I added a button and tried calling `SelectAll()` in the button click event, but that didn't do anything either. What's going on? Is this a bug?

How can I get around this?

---

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Create a new Windows Form Application in .NET 4.0 in Visual
   Studio 2010.
2. Add a `TextBox`, `MaskedTextBox`, and `Button` to the default form
3. Change the `Mask` property on the MaskedTextBox to "_____".
4. Add some event handlers:

   ```
   private void maskedTextBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     Debug.WriteLine("GotFocus");
     maskedTextBox1.SelectAll();
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     Debug.WriteLine("Click");
     maskedTextBox1.SelectAll();
   }
   ```
5. Run the program, entered some data into the MaskedTextBox, tab through controls back to it. It selects the contents of the MaskedTextBox.
6. Select the other TextBox. Try clicking on MaskedTextBox. Output shows that `GotFocus` event was called, but text doesn't get selected.
7. Try clicking on button in form. Text doesn't get selected.

*Tested in Visual Studio 2010 with .NET 4.0 in a Windows Forms Application project*

---

**Why this isn't a duplicate of [TextBox.SelectAll() does not work with TAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3197870/textbox-selectall-does-not-work-with-tab)**

If you notice, the title says "SelectAll doesn't work with *TAB*". In my case, it *does* work with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it *doesn't* work with the mouse - completely opposite scenario. The answer for that question is to use the `GotFocus` event. I'm already using the `GotFocus` event, but it doesn't work. That answer does not answer this question. It is clearly not a duplicate. If I'm wrong, please explain in the comments.

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97459/automatically-select-all-text-on-focus-in-winforms-textbox), it might help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `SelectAll()` is being overwritten by the default functionality of the masked textbox select.  I would use the `Enter` event, it allows for tabbed entry or mouse click entry to the masked text box.  You will most likely need to use the `BeginInvoke` method.  Try the code below.  It worked for me when I tried...

```
private void maskedTextBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BeginInvoke((Action) delegate { SetMaskedTextBoxSelectAll((MaskedTextBox) sender); });
}

private void SetMaskedTextBoxSelectAll(MaskedTextBox txtbox)
{
    txtbox.SelectAll();
}
```

Comment: Does the `BeginInvoke` just force the `SelectAll()` to run after the default functionality of the masked textbox is executed? I'd love to hear more on why this works if you don't mind expanding your answer a bit more.

Comment: I found a [less wordy way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1007612/945456) of doing BeginInvoke and have taken the liberty to edit the answer.

Comment: Here is some decent reading on BeginInvoke.  CodeProject can explain it much better than I can.  But yeah basically in your example BeginInvoke runs after the default functionality.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10311/What-s-up-with-BeginInvoke

Answer (score 1):

Executing Focus before Select All worked for me:

```
private void Masked_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ((MaskedTextBox)sender).Focus();
    ((MaskedTextBox)sender).SelectAll();
}
```

Comment: Does this work when the masked text box gets focus by being clicked on? It worked in other scenarios for me, but not that one.